# Проблема конструктора в классе User yii2

Tags: yii2

После переписывания метода signup в классе SignUpForm на следующий код:

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User($this->username, $this->password, $this->email);

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}
```

Написания конструктора в классе User и трейта InstantiateTrait
Конструктор:

```
public function __construct( string $username, string $password, string 
$email )
 {
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->setPassword($password);
    $this->created_at = time();
    $this->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    $this->generateAuthKey();
    parent::__construct();
 }
```

Трейт:

```
trait InstantiateTrait
{
  private static $_instance;
  private static $_prototype;
  public static function instance($refresh = false): self
  {
    if ($refresh || self::$_prototype === null) {
      self::$_instance = self::instantiate([]);
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }
  public static function instantiate($row): self
  {
    if (self::$_prototype === null) {
      $class = \get_called_class();
      self::$_prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', 
\strlen($class), $class));
    }
    $entity = clone self::$_prototype;
    $entity->init();
    return $entity;
  }
}
```

Во время регистрации и авторризации пользователя выходит ошибка : ArgumentCountError
текст: Too few arguments to function common\entities\User::__construct(), 0 passed in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/models/search/User.php on line 34 and exactly 3 expected
Как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: так в чем проблема? какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @peresada Во время регистрации и авторризации пользователя выходит ошибка : ArgumentCountError
текст: Too few arguments to function common\entities\User::__construct(), 0 passed in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/models/search/User.php on line 34 and exactly 3 expected
Как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: во-первых должно быть `return parent::__construct();` ошибка как раз происходит из-за того, что ты именно вызываешь метод construct родителя, и вызываешь его, не передавая ему аргументы

Comment: `return parent::__construct([$this->username, $this->password, $this->email]);` добавил вот это, все равно не работает

Comment: сейчас еще раз пересмотрел инфу, все-таки не нужен там return, но и аргументы все равно нужны, и передавать их нужно без квадратных скобок. Все-таки хочется понять, чего именно Вы хотите добиться и почему используете __construct?

Comment: Я хочу добиться атомарности и чтобы не писать один и тот же код при создании юзер а вразных частях сайта

Comment: И все равно не помогает, что вы посоветовали. Может это из-за версии Yii2 ? Делаю это по курсу Дмитрия Елисеева

Comment: я понял, что вы хотите, советую забить на __construct и использовать beforeSave(), прочитайте об этом подробнее в документации yii
`public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        // Place your custom code here

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: beforeSvae использовать в классе User ?

Comment: Я ответил ниже, да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из комментариев, понял наконец, что вы хотите. Советую воспользоваться методом beforeSave(), распологаться он должен в классе сущности User которая расширяет ActiveRecord. Вот пример кода (там не User, но принцип понятен, опробовал только что на своей модели) Прочесть об этом методе можно здесь http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            // $insert - постоянная переменная, для измненения данных объекта используйте $this->свойство
            // username и прочие внесенные данные в этом методе можно не дублировать
            $this->setPassword($this->password);
            $this->created_at = time();
            $this->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
            $this->generateAuthKey();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```